Fourier Transform of a Gauss-Hermite Function
I would like to compute the Fourier Transform of a Hermite function with general bandwidth $\sigma>0$. That is, I want to compute,
$$\mathscr{F}\left(e^{-\frac{x^2}{2\sigma^2}}H_k(x)\right)$$ where $H_k(x)=(-1)^ke^{x^2}\frac{d^k}{dx^k} e^{-x^2}$ is the Physicist's Hermite polynomial. Hermite polynomials are eigenfunctions of the Fourier Transform , so the calculation with $\sigma=1$ is relatively straightforward, but I am having trouble recreating a similar calculation as is with my additional $\sigma$ factor in the exponential.
Edit: My calculation and intuition lead me to believe that $$\mathscr{F}\left(e^{-\frac{x^2}{2\sigma^2}}H_k(x)\right)=(-i)^k e^{-\frac{\xi^2}{2\sigma^2}}H_k(\xi),$$
but based on some numerical calculations on Sage, I am not sure if I missed a factor of $\sigma$ popping out as well.
Any help would be much appreciated.

You could do a change of variable and use the formula for $H_k(\gamma x)$ in terms of the $H_i(x)$'s, see the multiplication formula (just above the paragraph “Explicit expression”).

Example $k=2$:
$$\mathcal{F}_x\left\exp \left(-\frac{x^2}{2 \sigma ^2}\right)\cdot H_2(x) \right=\sigma  e^{-\frac{1}{2} \xi ^2 \sigma ^2} \left(-4 \xi ^2 \sigma ^4+4 \sigma ^2-2\right)$$
Example $k=3$:
$$\mathcal{F}_x\left\exp \left(-\frac{x^2}{2 \sigma ^2}\right)\cdot H_3(x) \right=-4 i \xi  \sigma ^3 e^{-\frac{1}{2} \xi ^2 \sigma ^2} \left(2 \xi ^2 \sigma ^4-6 \sigma ^2+3\right)$$

@gpmath Could you show some details of your computation?

This is my computation with Mathematica: MSE_Q4963851

I've updated my answer, have a look ;)

(Partial answer)
Here is a restatement of the problem, somewhat related to Feynman's trick. Let's define the following parametrized Fourier transform :
$$
F_k(\xi,t) = \mathscr{F}\left[e^{-\frac{1}{2}tx^2}H_k(x)\right](\xi)
$$
Then, you may check that it satisfies to the partial differential equation :
$$
\frac{\partial F_k}{\partial t} = \frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^2F_k}{\partial\xi^2},
$$
which is nothing else than the well-known heat equation with unit diffusion coefficient. The boundary condition will be given by the eigenvalue equation for Hermite functions, i.e.
$$
F_k(\xi,t=1) = (-i)^ke^{-\frac{1}{2}\xi^2}H_k(\xi),
$$
while the solution you are looking for will be $F(\xi,t=1/\sigma^2)$.

Your approach seems to work, see Q4963851
